# Pretty print an array with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have an object named Puzzle and I'm calling .map on it in order to isolate the 'title' values.  I then use 'puts' in order to print them neatly but nothing is returned.

```
def puzzle_find
  title_array = self.puzzles.map { |s| s.title }
  puts title_array
end
#=> " "
```

If I don't use 'puts' then I get the array like this:

```
def puzzle_find
  title_array = self.puzzles.map { |s| s.title }
end  

#=> ["title 1", "title 2", "title 3"]
```

I'm trying to make the output look like this in my view:

```
title 1
title 2
title 3
```

thanks

Comment: The puzzle_find method should not be responsible for printing the array. Just return the array, and handle how you want to display it in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection of titles should be prepared in the controller (or exposed by the controller and retrieved in the model, or etc., as long as there's a collection of titles at the end of it all):

```
def controller_method
  @puzzles = ... whatever ...
  @titles = @puzzles.collect(&:title)
end
```

View:

```
<% @titles.each do |t| %>
  <%= t %><br/>
<% end %>
```

*(Or wrap it up in a partial, or use a helper. Above assumes scrubbed of HTML badness.)*

Answer (score 1):

```
title_array.each do |title|
  puts title
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi When you say "my view", I assume it is html.erb file.

Use join method to insert `<br/>` into your array:

```
def puzzle_find
  title_array = self.puzzles.map { |s| s.title }.join('<br/>')
end
```

If your "view" is about console outputs:

Use join method with `\n`:

```
def puzzle_find
  title_array = self.puzzles.map { |s| s.title }.join('\n')
end
```

Example in irb console:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :001 > puts ["a","b","c"].join("\n")
a
b
c
=> nil
```